# CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file) _ upgrading sameersbn/gitlab to latest

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

i'm trying to upgrade my `gitlab` from `11.5.0` version to `12.3.2`. 
postgreSQL image tag in my old docker-compose.yml file is: `postgresql 9.5-1`.

I tried with:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/master/docker-compose.yml

to upgrade, i did steps below:

1. pull redis:4.0.9-2
2. pull postgresql:10-2
3. pull gitlab:12.3.2

After `docker-compose down`, i updated the images tags in **docker-compose.yml** and then i ran:

`docker-compose up`

the **gitlab** is successfully run but it doesn't show my projects and users , it seems it didn't connect
to the DB volume or DB doesn't migrate well

here is my gitlab container full log:

```
error that i think its the issue couse : CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)

[root@localhost docker-gitlab-master]# docker logs ed6f439c9bad
Loading /etc/docker-gitlab/runtime/env-defaults
Initializing logdir...
Initializing datadir...
Installing configuration templates...
Configuring gitlab...
Configuring gitlab::database.......
Configuring gitlab::redis
Configuring gitlab::secrets...
Configuring gitlab::sidekiq...
Configuring gitlab::gitaly...
Configuring gitlab::monitoring...
Configuring gitlab::gitlab-workhorse...
Configuring gitlab::unicorn...
Configuring gitlab::timezone...
Configuring gitlab::rack_attack...
Configuring gitlab::ci...
Configuring gitlab::artifacts...
Configuring gitlab::lfs...
Configuring gitlab::uploads...
Configuring gitlab::mattermost...
Configuring gitlab::project_features...
Configuring gitlab::oauth...
Configuring gitlab::ldap...
Configuring gitlab::cron_jobs...
Configuring gitlab::backups...
Configuring gitlab::backups::schedule...
Configuring gitlab::registry...
Configuring gitlab::pages...
Configuring gitlab::sentry...
Configuring gitlab-shell...
Configuring nginx...
Configuring nginx::gitlab...
Migrating database...
2019-10-02 11:00:25,265 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-10-02 11:00:25,265 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cron.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gitaly.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gitlab-workhorse.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/groups.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/mail_room.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sidekiq.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sshd.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,266 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/unicorn.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:00:25,289 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-10-02 11:00:25,290 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-10-02 11:00:25,290 INFO supervisord started with pid 605
2019-10-02 11:00:26,292 INFO spawned: 'gitaly' with pid 626
2019-10-02 11:00:26,295 INFO spawned: 'gitlab-workhorse' with pid 627
2019-10-02 11:00:26,297 INFO spawned: 'unicorn' with pid 628
2019-10-02 11:00:26,299 INFO spawned: 'sidekiq' with pid 629
2019-10-02 11:00:26,302 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 630
2019-10-02 11:00:26,305 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 634
2019-10-02 11:00:26,308 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 639
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: gitaly entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: gitlab-workhorse entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: unicorn entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: sidekiq entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:00:27,716 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
NOTICE: trigger "trigger_84853438aac0" for relation "epics" does not exist, skipping
Clearing cache...
2019-10-02 11:01:16,126 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2019-10-02 11:01:16,127 INFO waiting for gitaly, gitlab-workhorse, unicorn, sidekiq, nginx, sshd, cron to die
2019-10-02 11:01:16,128 INFO stopped: cron (terminated by SIGTERM)
2019-10-02 11:01:16,128 INFO stopped: sshd (exit status 0)
2019-10-02 11:01:16,134 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2019-10-02 11:01:18,802 INFO stopped: sidekiq (exit status 0)
2019-10-02 11:01:18,806 INFO stopped: gitlab-workhorse (terminated by SIGTERM)
2019-10-02 11:01:19,392 INFO stopped: unicorn (exit status 0)
2019-10-02 11:01:19,392 INFO waiting for gitaly to die
2019-10-02 11:01:19,418 INFO stopped: gitaly (exit status 0)
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cron.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gitaly.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gitlab-workhorse.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/groups.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/mail_room.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sidekiq.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sshd.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,733 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/unicorn.conf" during parsing
2019-10-02 11:01:19,741 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-10-02 11:01:19,742 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-10-02 11:01:19,742 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-10-02 11:01:20,745 INFO spawned: 'gitaly' with pid 822
2019-10-02 11:01:20,748 INFO spawned: 'gitlab-workhorse' with pid 823
2019-10-02 11:01:20,751 INFO spawned: 'unicorn' with pid 824
2019-10-02 11:01:20,753 INFO spawned: 'sidekiq' with pid 825
2019-10-02 11:01:20,755 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 826
2019-10-02 11:01:20,757 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 828
2019-10-02 11:01:20,759 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 832
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: gitaly entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: gitlab-workhorse entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: unicorn entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: sidekiq entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-10-02 11:01:21,785 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Any idea?